# How can get TypeScript to correctly type check call to a generic function that in turns calls a function with a generic type parameter?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to write code very similar to this:

```
const globalState = {
  searchState: {
    id: "value"
  }
};

interface MapState<Result> {
  (state: any): Result;
}

interface SearchState {
  id: string;
}

interface HasSearchState {
  searchState: SearchState;
}

const createUseMapState = <State>() => {
  return (mapState: MapState<State>) => mapState(globalState);
};

const useHasSearchState = createUseMapState<HasSearchState>();

const useSearchState = (mapState?: <T>(state: SearchState) => T) => {
  if (mapState) {
    return useHasSearchState((hasState) => mapState(hasState.searchState));
  }
  return useHasSearchState((hasState) => hasState.searchState);
};

const useId = () => useSearchState((state) => state.id);  // <-- Error here!
```

Available in a [CodePen](https://codesandbox.io/s/522j37354?module=%2Fsrc%2Ferror.ts).

TypeScript (3.3.3) gives a TS2345 on the last line:

```
Argument of type '<T>(state: SearchState) => string' is not assignable to parameter of type '<T>(state: SearchState) => T'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T'.
```

If I change the last function to not use the intermediate function, it works:

```js
const useId = () => useHasSearchState((state) => state.searchState.id);
```

How can I declare the types of the `useSearchState` function so that its usage in `useId` type checks?

The context for the real-life code is [React](https://reactjs.org/) using [Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html), with the help of the [redux-hooks](https://github.com/epeli/redux-hooks) library.

I feel like this should type check correctly, but obviously I misunderstand something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lift T parameter to outer func.

```
const a = (m: <T>() => T) => { 
  return m();
}
// Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T'
a(() => 'Hey!');
```

But

```
const a = <T>(m: () => T) => { 
  return m();
}
// Ok!
a(() => 'Hey!');
```

Lets change your code

```
const useSearchState = <T>(mapState?: (state: SearchState) => T) => {
  if (mapState) {
    //                       Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'HasSearchState'.   
    return useHasSearchState((hasState) => mapState(hasState.searchState));
  }
  return useHasSearchState((hasState) => hasState.searchState);
};
```

Type checker works now, useHasSearchState has type (mapState: MapState) => HasSearchState. Add restriction:

```
const useSearchState = <T extends HasSearchState>(mapState?: (state: SearchState) => T) => {
```

It's clear error now

```
// Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'HasSearchState'.
const useId = () => useSearchState(state => state.id);
```